# JQuery Isotope Plugin Mysterious Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I'm currently using a tutorial to learn how to implement a JQuery plugin called "Isotope" in a wordpress theme that I'm building. Here is a link to the tutorial that I'm using: http://www.designlunatic.com/2011/08/isotope-tutorial/#wpcf7-f780-w1-o1

I have referenced the JQuery library in the functions.php file, and I have enqueued it and the isotope.js file (I've also registered this file) using the wp_enqueue_script (and wp_register_script) function. I know these files are being linked to because when I view the source code and click on the links I don't get an error. The files come up and they appear to be linked correctly via the wp_head function.

The problem I'm having is that the script to use isotope is giving me some kind of error in the console.

I've tried a few different methods but the error is usually:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"

The error is referring to the following script contained in the head of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('called');
            var $container = $('#content');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '*',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            });

            $('#nav a').click(function() {
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I have tried loading this as a separate script and registering/enqueue-ing it with a dependancy on JQuery which gave me basically the same error. I have also tried replacing '$' with 'JQuery' and placing the '$' inside the parameters for the functions. When I switch that I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'JQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function"

What am I doing wrong here? I've followed the tutorial instructions as close as I can. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: the **J** in jQuery is not uppercase. its lower case. 
so, if you change it to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`, it should work.

Comment: Seriously... I hate myself. You don't know how much of a headache that has been causing me. freaking stupid little error on my part, but that worked. If you want to put that as the answer to this question I'll check it off. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Also... why does this script not work with the '$' when jquery has already clearly been referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the **J** in jQuery is not uppercase. its lower case. so, if you change it to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` , it should work.

The error occurs if you have [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode enabled somewhere in your code.

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode. See the codex for [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) for more details.

Cheers! :)